# Sum of All Multiplication of Partitions

Tags: number-theory

$N$ is an integer.
$$ n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k \leq N $$
 $$n_i > 0$$

I want to find the sum of all possible $$ n_1 n_2 n_3 \cdots n_k$$ 
For eg: if $N=3$ and $k=2$, answer is
$$ (1\cdot1) + (1\cdot2) = 3$$

Is there any function, or a method to find this quantity if $N$ and $K$ are given?

Comment: are $n_1,n_2,...$ integer  ?

Comment: It seems you meant to imply $n_1\le n_2\le\cdots\le n_k$?

Comment: What's $K$? Or did you mean $k$?

Comment: Yes, they are integers. Yes, they are in non-decreasing order.

Comment: Sorry, k and K are same.

Comment: The idea is to clarify the question -- people shouldn't have to read through the comments to understand the question. (There's an edit button underneath the question.)

Answer (score 0):

$$n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k  \leq N\\$$write it as $$n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k +(n_{k+1})=N\\if \\n_{k+1}=1 \rightarrow n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k =N-1<N\\n_{k+1}=2 \rightarrow n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k =N-2<N\\n_{k+1}=3 \rightarrow n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k =N-3<N\\... $$ now $$n_1+n_2+n_3+...+n_k +n_{k+1}=N ,n_{i} \geq 1 \\\binom{N-1}{(k+1)-1}$$

Comment: This is fine, but I want sum of the product of these possible partitions.